# Classical versus rich comparison in Python

Tags: python, compare

I found the following Python code [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py):

```
def cmp_lt(x, y):
    # Use __lt__ if available; otherwise, try __le__.

    # In Py3.x, only __lt__ will be called.

    return (x < y) if hasattr(x, '__lt__') else (not y <= x)
```

I don't really understand what this function does. There is obviously a subtlety that I am missing here because I don't get how `x<y` could ever be different from `not y<=x` and under which settings these two statements would return different results, and even less why would we need to account for that. After a Google search I know that `__lt__` and `__le__` are related to rich comparisons, but that's it.

Comment: The comments in the code should be pretty informative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't get how `x<y` could ever be different from `not y<=x`

It is not, in fact it is exactly the same.

The thing is that if `x` is an instance of a class that didn't overridden `__lt__` then `x < y` will fail (and that's why there is `if hasattr(x, '__lt__')`). In that case instead of evaluating `x < y` it will try to evaluate `not y <= x`.

Comment: Thanks but why `if x is an instance of a class that didn't overridden __lt__ then x < y will fail`? What is exactly `__lt__` and what does it mean to override it?

Comment: Thanks. So it seems that we're looking at methods that define the behaviors of comparison operators. E.g., I might want to compare between words based on their length and not based on the order of the letters in the alphabet and change the behavior of comparisons operators accordingly for words. OK I get that. So as long as I am sure that x and y will always be numbers I'm safe to stay with `<` and `<=`?

Comment: " So as long as I am sure that x and y will always be numbers I'm safe to stay with < and <=?"

Yes you are.